# How can I prevent other admins from exporting a private key without knowing the password of a certificate key in IIS?

Tags: windows, iis, certificate

I have a Windows Server, where my many administrators have access.

The problem is, anyone who have access, can access the IIS. In the IIS, there are many certificates.
Right now, any admins can export the keys from all the certificates in IIS without knowing the password.
How can I prevent this?

I tried restricting to the IIS to one specific admin but couldn't find an option for this.

Comment: Certificates/private keys should be managed elsewhere, and when you install them on an IIS machine, choose to disallow export the private keys (but even so it is not as secure as you imagined). Not quite programming related, but Windows security management. So a security related forum is more suitable. If you work for a firm, escalate to the security experts or hire a consultant to learn more.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Sorry for the inappropriate post. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1)imort certs to IIS without possibilities of export them(check box in middle import dialog box).
2)reorganize locadmin policy on server
3) store original cert files in other restricted storeges

Comment: Got It! Thank you so much!

Comment: Be aware that everybody with admin access can use tool like mimikatz to export keys stored in software even if the export false is set to false. Real protection for keys can only be guaranteed with hardware security modules (HSM).